# How to apply a mask to a const void* address?

Tags: c, casting, memory-address

I work on an embedded target and want to define memory pools.

Memory addresses are represented as `void*`. However in a particular case, those addresses are cached and I want to uncache them to get directly the "real" hardware address.

I want to define the address of the beginning of `memory_area` (which is just a marker):

```
#define UNCACHE_MASK 0xABCDEF12UL // Value of the mask to apply
extern uint32_t memory_area; // Global, defined somewhere else
const void * virtual_address = &memory_area; // OK
const void * real_address = 
    (void*)(virtual_address | UNCACHE_MASK); // guilty line
```

Unfortunately, `GCC` won't let me do this:

```
error: invalid operands to binary | (have 'const void *' and 'long unsigned int')
```

In desperation I tried :

```
const void * real_address = 
    (void*)(((uint32_t)virtual_address) | UNCACHE_MASK); // guilty line
```

In vain:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

I really want to keep the `const` for safety : is it achievable ?

**[EDIT]**

- I am using `gcc` v4.9 (with `-std=gnu99` and a lot of `-Wxxx` flags) on Linux.
- The excerpt is from a `.h` file, variables are "global".

Comment: Here it probably doesn't matter, you know that your arch is 32 bit, but generally you should use `uintptr_t` for casting pointers to integers. (because the day you port your stuff to 64 bit, you will regret it :)

Comment: Right, thanks for the tip !

Comment: I don't think "cache" means what you think it does, here. It sounds as if you're talking about *virtual addresses*, which is not a caching concept. Caching doesn't change addresses.

Comment: @unwind Ok so in my case I do need to change the address, maybe I've been misguided by whoever named the mask. Feel free to edit my question to use the proper terms !

Comment: You may be interested in the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161764/address-vs-expression-on-address-in-static-initializer-in-c

Comment: The second warning you are getting because you probably have virtual_address as a global and try to initialize it with a non-constant expression. So you have two different problems in your code.

Comment: @Coconop Hey, did you by any chance upvote a lot of my answers 10 minutes ago?

Comment: @unwind: memory is probably mirrored at two addresses, once cached, and once uncached. Some MIPS processors do this.

Comment: @user2501 I just upvoted the one below: someone loves you but it wasn't me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign this using your bitwise-OR expression inside a function.  You cannot do the initialization at global scope as you have shown, because indeed the value is not known to the compiler (maybe in C++, but not in C).  If you add the casts and move the assignment inside a function scope, it will work.

When you say this:

```
const void * real_address
```

It means "real_address is a pointer to constant memory of unknown type."  If you want the pointer to also not be modifiable (in addition to what it points to), you can do this:

```
const void * const real_address
```

But then you won't be able to initialize it inside a function as you need to do.  I suppose you could cast away the constness inside the function, but this may not even be legal in C.

Comment: It's not possible to assign value to `real_address` in function if you define it `void const * const`.

Comment: @user694733: thanks, I fixed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I finally chose to give up the `const`, just declare it as global and set the address within a function.

Answer (score 5):

Simply make a define. It cannot be accidentally changed.

```
#define real_address  ( (void*)( (uint32_t)virtual_address | UNCACHE_MASK ) )
```

The extra instruction or two per usage aren't very expensive.

Also add a const keyword to the `virtual_address` variable, so it cannot be changed.

```
const void* const virtual_address = ...
```

Comment: Good tip, it actually solves the issue on my code excerpt, however I am looking for optimizations and `real_address` is used elsewhere for other computations and I want to avoid those extra-instructions.

Comment: If this re-computation is really a bottleneck (I doubt it) you could  try to store the value once at the beginning in a variable. If you'd use that variable often, it should always be hot in the cache and not incure much overhead when reloading.