# Address vs. expression on address in static initializer in C

Tags: c

(This question was inspired by investigating an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160080/how-to-apply-a-mask-to-a-const-void-address))

I have a code sample that initializes two global static variables: one is a pointer to extern variable, another is an expressioon computed from that pointer:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define UNCACHE_MASK 0xABCDEF12UL // Value of the mask to apply

extern int memory_area;

const void * virtual_address = &memory_area;

const uintptr_t int_address = ((uintptr_t)&memory_area) | UNCACHE_MASK;
```

When I compile I get the following:

```
$ gcc -c  test.c
test.c:6:1: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
 const uintptr_t int_address = ((uintptr_t)&memory_area) | UNCACHE_MASK;
 ^
```

I am not much of an expert in C, but it seems that if `&memory area` is good for initializing `virtual_address`, it should also be good for initializing `int_address`.

What am I missing?

(gcc version 4.8.2, Cygwin on Win 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal definition of *constant expressions* of C language allow converting integer values to pointer types (to form *address constants*), but not the other way around (to form *arithmetic constant expressions*). It explicitly states that "cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to arithmetic types". For this reason the `(uintptr_t) &memory_area` bit violates the requirements imposed on *arithmetic constant expressions*. The expression is formally not a constant expression and therefore cannot be used in initializer for an object with static storage duration.

So, in short, `&memory_area` is an *address constant*, but `(uintptr_t) &memory_area` is not an *arithmetic constant expression*.

But it is indeed strange to see that GCC does not allow it as an extension.

Comment: Would need dynamic initialization if ASLR is active, perhaps that's why.

Comment: @Deduplicator Do I understand you correctly? ASLR can update exact values of addresses stored in static memory, but cannot update the constants derived from such values?

Comment: @Arkadiy: Derived constants, sure, but how complex before you need full-scale runtime-initialization?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Good point. They had to draw the line somewhere. Yet, the language allows some address arithmetic in address constants, like `[]` and `.` operators. Allowing conversions to integers and some additional arithmetic doesn't seem as something too complicated.

Comment: @Deduplicator: not really related to ASLR, happens for every relocatable object. Relocations only allow addends. `+ ADDEND`, instead of `| MASK`, would work.

Comment: For reference: C11 (draft) 6.6 p7 _More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following: [...] an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an integer constant expression._